# Blender render color different from the actual one

Tags: model, 3d, blender

So, here's what i created
[image]

But on rendering, the color changes....
[image]

I'm using cycles and HDRI.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue?

Comment: In my case it seems to use a different material, but I don't know why. I'm getting an orange car but the preview the car is yellow